# Plotting a lot of data in Python histogram

Tags: python, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram in Python but run out of memory because there are too many numbers in the text file that I am processing.  The the format of my text file looks like this:

size - reads - writes

Size is a single number
Reads and writes are many numbers separated by spaces.

So for example:  10 - 1 23 245 2567 - 2 32 342 1231

reads and writes are also sorted already, if that matters.

The text file only contains 10 lines of data used for plotting but each line is very long.  The entire text file is multiple gigabytes.

I am making two graphs at once, one for reads and another for writes.  Each graph looks like this http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/_images/histogram_demo_extended_06.png
but has 10 bars for each bin instead of 3 bars.

The problem is that I keep running out of memory.  Is there a way to take in elements of a single line in the textfile, one by one instead of taking in the entire line?  I've searched for similar things on stackoverflow but they are a bit different from the problem I have in which a single line contains a lot of data and that I want a histogram with multiply bars in each bin.  I'm not very familiar with python either as this was the first thing I've made with it.  Thanks a lot

Here is my code which runs out of memory of large text files..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import re                       # regular expressions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # plotting

import numpy as np

datafile = "x264.data"
benchmark_name = "x264"
# Set up a dict/map for the data
stuff = []

with open(datafile,'r') as ifile:
    for line in ifile:

        # Remove whitespace
        line = line.strip()

        if not line:
            # Skip empty lines
            continue

        if line[0] == "$":
            print "something is wrong"

        if line[0] == "&":
            print "some missing alloc routine not accounted for"

        if line[0] not in "0123456789":
            continue

        # Line starts with a number, therefore data

        # Split data using the delimeter
        column_data = re.split("-", line)
        # Remove any leftover whitespace
        column_data = [string_data.strip() for string_data in column_data]

        # Get the Address as an integer
        maxSize = str(column_data[0])

        reads = column_data[1].strip()
        reads = [ int(s) for s in re.split('\s+', reads) ]

        writes = column_data[2].strip()
        writes = [ int(s) for s in re.split('\s+', writes) ]

        stuff += [[maxSize, reads, writes]]


###############################################################################
# PLOTTING

# See http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html
# for info on making barcharts

# Size plotting data


common_params = dict(bins=20, label=[stuff[0][0], stuff[1][0], stuff[2][0], stuff[3][0], stuff[4][0], stuff[5][0], stuff[6][0], stuff[7][0], stuff[8][0], stuff[9][0]])

reads = plt.figure()
ax1 = reads.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title(benchmark_name + "reads")
ax1.set_xlabel("instruction #")
ax1.set_ylabel("# of accesses")


read_data = [s[1] for s in stuff[0:10]]
write_data = [s[2] for s in stuff[0:10]]

ax1.hist(read_data, **common_params)
ax1.set_yscale('log',nonposy='clip')

lgd=ax1.legend(ncol = 1, title = "maxSize", loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

#ax1.plt.savefig(benchmark_name + " reads.png")
reads.savefig(benchmark_name + " reads.png",bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
writes = plt.figure()
ax2 = writes.add_subplot(111)

ax2.set_title(benchmark_name + "writes")
ax2.set_xlabel("instruction #")
ax2.set_ylabel("# of accesses")

ax2.hist(write_data, **common_params)
ax2.set_yscale('log',nonposy='clip')


lgd=ax2.legend(ncol = 1, title = "maxSize", loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

writes.savefig(benchmark_name + " writes.png",bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```